# Using OrdinalEncoder to transform categorical values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which has the following columns:

```
No  Name  Sex  Blood  Grade  Height  Study
1   Tom   M    O      56     160     Math
2   Harry M    A      76     192     Math
3   John  M    A      45     178     English
4   Nancy F    B      78     157     Biology
5   Mike  M    O      79     167     Math
6   Kate  F    AB     66     156     English
7   Mary  F    O      99     166     Science
```

I want to change it to be something like this:

```
No  Name  Sex  Blood  Grade  Height  Study
1   Tom   0    0      56     160     0
2   Harry 0    1      76     192     0
3   John  0    1      45     178     1
4   Nancy 1    2      78     157     2
5   Mike  0    0      79     167     0
6   Kate  1    3      66     156     1
7   Mary  0    0      99     166     3
```

I know there is a library that can do it

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
```

Which I've tried this but it did not work

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
enc.fit(df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]])
```

Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong and how to do it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You were almost there !

Basically the `fit` method, prepare the encoder (fit on your data i.e. prepare the mapping) but don't transform the data.

You have to call `transform` to transform the data , or use `fit_transform` which fit and transform the same data.

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
enc.fit(df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]])
df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]] = enc.transform(df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]])
```

or directly

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]] = enc.fit_transform(df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]])
```

Note: The values won't be the one that you provided, since internally the fit method use `numpy.unique` which gives result sorted in alphabetic order and not by order of appearance.

As you can see from `enc.categories_`

````
[array(['F', 'M'], dtype=object),
 array(['A', 'AB', 'B', 'O'], dtype=object),
 array(['Biology', 'English', 'Math', 'Science'], dtype=object)]```
````

Each value in the array is encoded by it's position.
(F will be encoded as 0 , M as 1)

Comment: didn't work, after running that line still have Male/Female not 0/1  !!!

Comment: It's really weird , as you can see it works  https://pasteboard.co/Iitfx2g.png on my side.

Comment: Did you found the answer ? Maybe the problem exists because the dataframe you are not taking the original dataframe but a slice ?

Comment: I want to transform the data with ordingalencoder, the run an statistical model (for example regression) and then express the result using the original categories.
How can I reverse the transformation?

Answer (score 31):

I think it is important to point out that this is not an example for an ordinal encoding of variables. Sex, Blood and Study should all not have an ordinal scale (and was also not suggested by the person, who asked the question). Ordinal data has a ranking (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data) Those examples here do not have a ranking.

In the case that your variable is a target variable you can use the LabelEncoder.(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Then you can do something like:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

for col in ["Sex","Blood", "Study"]:
    df[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[col])
```

If your variables are features you should use the Ordinalencoder for accomplishing this. (See comments to my answer).

The naming for the Ordinalencoder is quite unfortunate as "ordinal" is seen from a mathematical and not a statistical naming perspective.

More on the difference between ordinal- and labelencoder in sklearn: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder

Comment: You have a point here, but it's also important to note that I don't think LabelEncoder works in Pipelines very well. From what I gathered online, it is ONLY intended for your target or response variable. So, to do what OP wants to do, they actually recommend using the OrdinalEncoder for this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please back up your arguments with any resources? I also don't understand what you mean. I am happy to learn :)

Comment: Sure, in the top of the userguide, it says very specifically that this is only to transform the target and not for encoding features: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#preprocessing-targets

You can also see this echoed in this github issue response: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12720

Comment: You are right. I think the issue is the use of the word "ordinal" which is not seen from a statistical point of view, but rather a mathematical one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

@Createdd is right. Even though "Sex", "Blood" and "Study" are categorical attributes, there are 2 kinds of categorical attributes: ordinal and nominal.

If you use OrdinalImputer for a nominal attribute most machine learning models will make the following assumption: Math (0) < English (1) < Biology (2) < Science (3). When in reality this should not be the case: "English" is not between "Math" and "Biology" or in any other order. A real ordinal attribute would be something like a rating: "Very Bad" (0), "Bad" (1), "Neutral" (2), "Good" (3), "Very Good" (4).

The correct answer should be to use OneHotEncoder for the "Sex", "Blood", "Study" attributes (because they are nominal attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to apply ordinal encoding using sklearn apply on dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "gender": ["man", "women", "child", "man", "women", "child"],
        "age": [40, 40, 10, 50, 50, 8],
    }
)


def ordinal_encoding(genders):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(genders)
    return le.transform(genders)


encoded_genders = ordinal_encoding(df["gender"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my opinion:

First create the encoder:

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
```

The names of the columns which their values are needed to be transformed are:

Sex, Blood, Study

Use `enc.fit_transform()` to fit and then transform the values of each column to numbers as shown below:

```
X_enc = enc.fit_transform(df["Sex", "Blood", "Study"])
```

Finally, replace these transformed values with the original ones (which are in the main dataframe):

```
df["Sex", "Blood", "Study"] = pd.DataFrame(X_enc, columns=["Sex", "Blood", "Study"])
```

The answer:

```
No  Name   Sex  Blood  Grade  Height  Study
1   Tom    1.0  3.0    56     160     2.0
2   Harry  1.0  0.0    76     192     2.0
3   John   1.0  0.0    45     178     1.0
4   Nancy  0.0  2.0    78     157     0.0
5   Mike   1.0  3.0    79     167     2.0
6   Kate   0.0  1.0    66     156     1.0
7   Mary   0.0  3.0    99     166     3.0
```