# Is there a smart way to apply ordinal encoder (based on different categories) to multiple variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I have multiple variables with text values which I want to convert into numeric values by ordinal encoder. But these variables are following different ordinal logic. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {"attr1":["Excellent", "Fair", "Fair", "Good", "Poor"],
     "attr4":["Fair", "Good", "Good", "Excellent", "Excellent"],
     "attr2":["Finished", "Unfinished", "Partially Finished", "Finished", "Unfinished"],
     "attr3":["Satisfied", "Unsatisfied", "Unsatisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied"]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

You can notice that "attr1" and "attr4" share the same unique values. To convert the text values into numeric:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
# Assign attributes to different lists based on the values
attr_list1 = ["attr1", "attr4"]
attr_list2 = ["attr2"]
attr_list3 = ["attr3"]

# Create categories to instruct how ordinal encoder should work
cat1 = ["Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Excellent"]
cat2 = ["Unfinished", "Partially Finished", "Finished"]
cat3 = ["Unsatisfied", "Satisfied"]

# Initialize the encoder
encoder1 = OrdinalEncoder(categories = [cat1])
encoder2 = OrdinalEncoder(categories = [cat2])
encoder3 = OrdinalEncoder(categories = [cat3])

def ord_encode(attr_list, encoder):
    for attr in attr_list:
        data[attr] = encoder.fit_transform(data[[attr]])
    return data

data = ord_encode(attr_list1, encoder1)
data = ord_encode(attr_list2, encoder2)
data = ord_encode(attr_list3, encoder3)
```

I find my solution very inefficient and awkward. Imagine I have 20+ attributes with 4 or 5 different kinds of categories. I am wondering is there any smart way to resolve my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sklearn-pandas` can be used to quickly do this for you. I would build a column to category mapping and then use `DataFrameMapper` to create a pipeline for me.

```py
column_to_cat = {
    "attr1": cat1,
    "attr4": cat1,
    "attr2": cat2,
    "attr3": cat3
}

mapper_df = DataFrameMapper(
    [
        ([col], OrdinalEncoder(categories = [cat])) for col, cat in column_to_cat.items()
    ],
    df_out=True
)
mapper_df.fit_transform(data.copy())
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
d = {"attr1":["Excellent", "Fair", "Fair", "Good", "Poor"],
     "attr4":["Fair", "Good", "Good", "Excellent", "Excellent"],
     "attr2":["Finished", "Unfinished", "Partially Finished", "Finished", "Unfinished"],
     "attr3":["Satisfied", "Unsatisfied", "Unsatisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied"]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

# Create categories to instruct how ordinal encoder should work
cat1 = ["Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Excellent"]
cat2 = ["Unfinished", "Partially Finished", "Finished"]
cat3 = ["Unsatisfied", "Satisfied"]

# Assign attributes to different lists based on the values
column_to_cat = {
    "attr1": cat1,
    "attr4": cat1,
    "attr2": cat2,
    "attr3": cat3
}


mapper_df = DataFrameMapper(
    [
        ([col], OrdinalEncoder(categories = [cat])) for col, cat in column_to_cat.items()
    ],
    df_out=True
)
mapper_df.fit_transform(data.copy())
```

Comment: Thanks! It is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, there is a neater way.

```
    enc = OrdinalEncoder()
    enc.fit(df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]])
    df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]] = enc.transform(df[["Sex","Blood", "Study"]])
```

Source: [Using OrdinalEncoder to transform categorical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502864/using-ordinalencoder-to-transform-categorical-values)